# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath' android studio kotlin compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, mobile, android-jetpack-compose

When i click run app, shows this error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
```

I’ve been studying lessons that have been around for over a year, there are old libraries and methods, apparently, now a lot of things don’t work for me based on those examples, I had to look for answers... and I think I found them, it stopped highlighting errors, but now the project won’t start...

The examples use the library implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.19.1:0") and implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.19.1") , but I use 0.27 .1.0, I was looking for a long time to solve the problem with rememberPagerState and pagerTabIndicatorOffset, I had to change import androidx.compose.material3.TabRow to import androidx.compose.material.TabRow to make it work, the project breaks after importing the libraries!!! what can be done? how to change the code, optimize it for all new updates

My code

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class, ExperimentalPagerApi::class)
@Composable
fun TabLayout() {
    val tabList = listOf("HOURS", "DAYS")
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState()
    val tabIndex = pagerState.currentPage
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 5.dp, end = 5.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))

    ) {
        TabRow(
            selectedTabIndex = tabIndex,
            indicator = { pos ->
                TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    Modifier.pagerTabIndicatorOffset(pagerState = pagerState, tabPositions = pos)
                )
            },
            backgroundColor = BlueLight,
            contentColor = Color.White
        ) {
            tabList.forEachIndexed { index, text ->
                Tab(selected = false,
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    }, text = {
                        Text(text = text)
                    }
                )


            }
        }

        HorizontalPager(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f),
            state = pagerState,
            count = tabList.size,
        ) { index ->

        }

    }
}
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.27.1:0")
    implementation("com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.27.1")

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.0.0-rc01")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using these dependencies:

implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.23.0"

implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.23.0"

If the error only started occurring after you added the two dependencies at the top of your implementations, it is most probably due to the dependencies. I have tested the above two dependencies, and they work for me.

Best of luck going forward, and happy coding!